# MS Access - sql expression for allow null?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, alter-table, alter-column

I use MS Access (2003) database. Once I create a column I set NOT NULL using sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ALTER column myColumn INTEGER not null
```

Is there a way to change it back to allow null values? I already tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ALTER column myColumn INTEGER null
```

but nothing...

Comment: Did you receive an error or did literally "nothing" happen?

Comment: No errors, but nothing changed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant specify `null` in `ALTER TABLE` (although `not null` is allowed)

See the below [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177883%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and also this [discussion on this toppic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5feef52c-85a8-4041-9c88-36aef2afe4cf/how-to-change-not-null-column-to-a-null-column-using-sql)

**Syntax**

```
ALTER TABLE table {ADD {COLUMN field type[(size)] [NOT NULL]     [CONSTRAINT index] |     ALTER COLUMN field type[(size)] |     CONSTRAINT multifieldindex} |     DROP {COLUMN field I CONSTRAINT indexname} }
```

**Old School Solution**:-

- create a new temporray field as null with the same datatype
- update the new temporary field to the existing NOT NULL field
- drop the old NOT NULL field
- create the droped column with the same datatype again without NOT NULL
- update the existing field to the temporary field
- if there have been indices on the existing field, recreate these
- drop the temporary field

Comment: It allows me to specify null in alter table, but it has no effect and that is my problem. I saw your solution in some other places but I was hoping I would not need to do that this way.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using `MODIFY` :-

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 MODIFY myColumn INT NULL;
```

Comment: Could you please try again and tel me the Syntax error which you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to use DAO directly on the table.
Set db.TableDefs(strTable1).Fields(strFieldName).Required = false